# How can I use modules in the browser, but also refer to variables and functions from within DevTools?

Tags: javascript

I have my HTML setup like this:

```html
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

and all the ES6 modules work fine. The only problem is I now can't refer to anything from within DevTools (like using the Console and typing in a variable to see it's value or using a function manually).
How do I import modules whilst being able to use the DevTools? Thanks!

Comment: can you show some example code with an example of the problem you are having

Comment: It's not code, that all works fine. The problem is not being able to debug the code using DevTools when it's type is a module.

Comment: You can set breakpoints where the module is called and then "Step Into" via the debugger. Also if you want to just checkout the API of a module [look here](/q/63784737).

Comment: ugh! this is NOT acceptable that the devtools don't work with module variables. In my view it's a browser bug that you can't do this.  a debugging environment in which you can't inspect state is crippled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else interested, if you're comfortable with it, **use a bundler like Webpack**. I don't believe (at least at this point) that the browser will by itself be able to use the DevTools on modules (the other solutions are quite janky, and aren't fantastic to work with).

Hopefully in the future, when all major browsers will be able to support ES6 modules without a bundler, we'll be able to use DevTools.

Comment: [Related](/q/30648101)

Answer (score 5):

One way to make a variable accessable within DevTools is to create it on the window object:

```js
// Variable in your module
var importantNumber = 1;

window.importantNumber = importantNumber;
```

This method works fine if you just have a couple of variables, but if you need to have access to a lot more variables within DevTools, I would recommend you go to the sources-tab in DevTools, search for your module and adding a breakpoint. When the execution pauses, you have access to all the variables within that module on the DevTools console.

Comment: But wouldn't this be difficult if you're trying to debug long files?

Comment: Depends on your needs. If you only need to debug a small portion of a large file, I would go with the 'window' method, but if you need to debug all the code, I would take place a breakpoint where you know all variables are available and debug from there.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be able to refer to variables created within the module from the console's global scope, you'll have to deliberately expose each such variable that you want to be visible from the console. Either assign each variable to `window` (probably not a good idea - the whole point of modules is to make things more modular, without global pollution), or perhaps assign a single object to `window`, to which you assign module variables. For example:

```js
// in the console:

setTimeout(() => {
  window.myModule.foo();
  console.log(window.myModule.bar);
});
```

```html
<script type="module">
  function foo() {
    console.log('doing foo');
  }
  const bar = 'a string bar';
  
  const thisModule = { foo, bar };
  window.myModule = thisModule;
  // If you ever reassign variables, you'll have to reassign them on thisModule too
  // or, only reference and reassign properties of thisModule, rather than create independent variables
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Using a Helper

I personally use a little helper function in development that allows me to expose a bunch a variables in a single expression. For example, it makes the following two blocks equivalent:

```
window.playerOne = playerOne;
window.someClass = someClass;
window.localData = localData;

globalize({playerOne, someClass, localData});
```

The helper looks like this:

```js
const globalize = function(variables) {
    Object.entries(variables).forEach(([name, value]) => window[name] = value);
};
```